# Would this be an appropriate situation to use a repeater?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, repeater

I just moved to a new house in an older neighborhood with lots of brick walls. After getting internet installed yesterday and setting up my router, I walked around the house testing the signal with my iPhone. Right next to the router, I get about 25 Mbps. Most other places in the house I get between 20-25 Mbps. There is a single room, however, where I get about 1Mbps. It happens to be the room that is at the furthest possible point from the router, which also happens to be my office - a room where a good internet connection is critical.

Would this be a situation in which a repeater would help? My understanding is that they are most useful in extending the effective range of a wireless signal, but I'm not sure if effective range is the issue or not - my wireless devices in this 1Mbps room claim a roughly 75%+ strength signal. Moving the modem and router is unfortunately not an option, so other than using a repeater, I'm not sure that I have any other options.

Comment: There's no way to answer this question short of trying.  It might help, it might not, it really depends on the exact electromagnetic characteristics of your particular signal in your particular building.  You'll just have to try.  (I suppose we could discuss the LIKELIHOOD of it helping, but that's Not Constructive™.)

Comment: how fast is your internet connection speed? compare speed with your computer standing near the router and in the office (download something from a fast server, compare the difference). I personally would not rely on speed meters and stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using powerline network adapters?
I have used these on several occasions in situations like yours and was very pleased with the results. If you then need wireless in the office room, then use a wireless access point.

Comment: I agreee I am using these for several difficult spots in the house and they work well. Depends on what data speed needs are.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to admit this, but I had actually never heard of these until you mentioned them. This seems like it would be good - thanks for cluing me onto this.